# Добавление объекта в массив объектов через input

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Подскажите, как добавить в массив объектов новый объект через html форму

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
    <div id="forms">
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
        <input id="surname" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия">
        <input id="middleName" type="text" placeholder="Отчество">
        <input id="birthday" type="text" placeholder="Дата рождения">
        <input id="year" type="text" placeholder="Год начала обучения">
        <input id="faculty" type="text" placeholder="Факультет">
        <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="submit" onclick="getArr()">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
function getArr() {

    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    let middleName = document.getElementById('middleName').value;
    let birthday = document.getElementById('birthday').value;
    let year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    let faculty = document.getElementById('faculty').value;

    let students = [
        {
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            middleName: '',
            birthday: '',
            year: '',
            faculty: '',
        },
        {
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            middleName: '',
            birthday: '',
            year: '',
            faculty: '',
        },
        {
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            middleName: '',
            birthday: '',
            year: '',
            faculty: '',
        },
    ]

    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот готовая функция.
Обратите внимание на кнопку в верстке, она теперь `button` вместо `input`.

```js
function getArr() {
  let inputAll = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#forms input'));
  let arr = [];
  let obj = {};

  let checkFieldsLength = inputAll.every((el) => el.value.length);

  if (checkFieldsLength) {
    for (const input of inputAll) {
      obj[input.id] = input.value;
    }
    arr.push(obj);
    return console.log(arr);
  }
  return alert('Не все поля заполнены');
}
```

```html
<div id="forms">
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
  <input id="surname" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия">
  <input id="middleName" type="text" placeholder="Отчество">
  <input id="birthday" type="text" placeholder="Дата рождения">
  <input id="year" type="text" placeholder="Год начала обучения">
  <input id="faculty" type="text" placeholder="Факультет">
  <button type="button" name="button" id="button" value="submit" onclick="getArr()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

```
students.push({
  name: name,
  ...
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!